# ionic 4 - loading spinner not working in infinite scroll

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

the loading spinner is not showing at the bottom of the infinite scroll even after i have added the loadingSpinner line into the code

[image: There is now loading spinner at all even i have already added the loadingSpinner line into the code]

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="getProducts($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't checked your code but I am sure this occured because in
Ionic4 there is a change in the kind of events that are emitted. In Ionic v3 we were emitting synthetic Angular events, but in V4 we've emitted HTML events, meaning you need to access the complete method from the event `target`. The correct way to handle this now is with `$event.target.methodName()`

**Solution -**

```
 doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        this.items.push(this.items.length);
      }

      infiniteScroll.target.complete(); // this is how you need to call in v4
    }, 500);
  }
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-ajuju5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Faction-sheet%2Faction-sheet.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4:

```html
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="getProducts($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data…">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Ionic 3:

```html
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="getProducts($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

More Info with Ionic Docs:

[Ionic 4 - infinite-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll-content)

[Ionic 3 - infinite-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/)

Comment: buddy are you sure this solution will work! please check it once